# Deutsches Äquivalent zu »My Word Is Not Gospel«!

Tags: idiom, phrase-request

Auf Englisch, wenn man seine Meinung äußert und gleichzeitig betonen will, dass sie nur *eine* Meinung und nicht unbedingt wahr ist, und ihr nicht wie ein Gesetz zu folgen ist, sagt man

> My word is not gospel!

Was ist die äquivalente Redewendung auf Deutsch?

Comment: To tell someone their word is (not?) gospel you say `Dein Wort in Gottes Ohr`

Comment: @BernhardDöbler: Das sagt man zwar, aber nicht bei der Gelegenheit. Infinity spricht von einer Aussage, die man über eine eigene Aussage macht. "Mein Wort in Gottes Ohr" sagt man nicht.

Comment: Die Bibel wird im deutschen Sprachraum nur noch von einer verschwindenden Minderheit als wahr und verbindlich betrachtet, deswegen sind derartige Redewendung wohl stark aus der Mode gekommen, Paul Frosts Vorschlag Nr. 2 wird aber noch verstanden und erregt auch keinen Anstoss.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach kann man das auch genau so wie ich in diesem Kommentar ausdrücken. Ich halte das jedenfalls für eine gangbare Alternative. Ich mag mich irren, aber noch stärker muss man die Unverbindlichkeit gewiss nicht ausdrücken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solche Redewendungen sind nur schwer in andere Sprachen zu übersetzen. Hier einige Vorschläge:

1. Meine Worte sind nicht in Stein gemeißelt.
2. Ich verkündige hier nicht das Evangelium.
3. Ich bin nicht unfehlbar. *Variante*: Ich bin nicht unfehlbar wie der Papst.

Answer (score 6):

> Ich habe (auch) nicht die Weisheit mit Löffeln gefressen!
>   Ich habe die Weisheit (auch) nicht für mich gepachtet!

Beide verneinen Redewendungen
[¹](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Weisheit+gepachtet)
[²](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Weisheit+mit+L%C3%B6ffeln+fressen),
die vorwiegend unverneint und ironisch oder kritisch genutzt werden.
Sie können aber auch wie hier verneint und nicht ironisch genutzt werden.

Ähnlich wie bei »My word is not gospel« kommen beide Redewendungen mit einem Augenzwinkern daher.

Comment: Den zweiten Satz kenne ich in der Fassung: Ich habe die _Wahrheit_ nicht gepachtet.

Answer (score 1):

I might say something like:

> Ihr braucht meine Worte nicht unbedingt auf die Waagschale legen.

This makes use of the idiomatical expression "etwas auf die Waagschale/Goldwaage legen" (see Duden link for [Waagschale](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Waagschale)).

[redensarten-index.de](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~etwas+%2F+jedes+Wort+auf+die+Waagschale+legen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%255B%255D) provides plenty of examples and claims that the expression is already found in texts from Antiquity (Varro, Cicero). The expression became popular in German with Luther's translation of the Bible:

> "Du wägest dein Gold und Silber ein; warum wägest du nicht auch deine Worte auf der Goldwaage?" (Sirach 28,25)